# QField error messages

Tags: qfield

I'm having a problem in the process of packaging a project to QField, while I was working with the same files before and there was no problem at all.
The QGIS version I'm working with now is 3.22.12, and in QField version 4.2.0.

I've tried quite a few different things than what I've read so far to no avail.
The messages displayed are :

> Non ASCII character detected in the layer filename. Working with file paths that are not in ASCII might cause problems. It is highly recommended to rename them to ASCII encoded paths.

> Layer does not use UTF-8, but Windows-1253 encoding. Working with layers that do not use UTF-8 encoding might cause problems. It is highly recommended to convert them to UTF-8 encoded layers.

> The project check provides automatic feedback for some common mistakes when using QFieldSync and QFieldCloud. Lines starting with ERROR show problems in your project configuration that must be fixed before  proceeding. Lines starting with WARNING are suggestions what you can improve.

What could I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: You mean, besides not using non-ASCII field names and non-UTF paths?

Comment: Yes exactly.
although most of the time the message refers to the ASCII code.